# Gridview with delete option

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a GridView which is like:

```
File Name   DateTimeUploaded    Type     
    Resume  1/13/2012 7:52:59 AM    .docx   Delete
    tiger   1/18/2012 7:56:31 AM    .docx   Delete
    Woods   1/18/2012 7:56:42 AM    .xlsx   Delete
    tiger   1/18/2012 7:57:43 AM    .xlsx   Delete
```

In gridview_rowdeleting I have :

```
GridView1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I click on delete of second row which has tiger, the second and fourth rows get deleted. But I want to delete only the second row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on what you have defined as the [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) for the grid, if you are using the "File Name" then anything named Tiger in your example would get deleted.

Comment: Ya I have defined DatakeyNames as File Name. Is there any alternative?

Comment: The DataKeyName should be a unique identifier for the record normally, a primary key if you are getting this data from a database table

Comment: Actually I have  a primary key ID which I dont want to display in gridview. How can I use this undisplayed ID column in gridview for deleting a record.

Comment: Just have the pk in the grid, check its properties and set visible to false, then set the datakeyname to the name of the pk field, you should be all set

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
GridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
```